# Paginate does not exist in Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'd like to paginate a page. I'm using this code in my controller:

```
$docItems = DocumentationItem::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get()->paginate(5);
```

and this in my view file:

```
{{ $docItems->withQueryString()->links() }}
```

but I am getting this error:

> Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::paginate does not
> exist.

I've checked similar questions here but none of the answers seemed to work for me. I'm using Laravel 7. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `->get()` returns a `Collection`, which does not have a `Paginate` method. Your code should be: `DocumentationItem::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(5);` (just remove the `->get()`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can not paginate after fetching data from db.

when you call `get()` method all `DocumentationItem` will be fetched from db.

insteadd you should use paginate without `get`:

```
$docItems = DocumentationItem::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(5);
```